# How to run a Two Way ANOVA in SAS?

Tags: anova, sas

I have a data set that looks like below. I have to find if the scores are different across the four days. I understand I need to run a Two Way ANOVA for this test. I'm quite new to SAS if anyone could help me how to go about this? Should I be rearranging my data?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose your dataset name is old:

```
data new;
set old;
y=round1score; round = 1; output;
y=round2score; round = 2; output;
y=round3score; round = 3; output;
y=round4score; round = 4; output;
run;

proc mixed data=new;
class player round;
model y = round;
random intercept/subject = player;
run;
```

Comment: It's tricky. Why do I need a blank line to get the line break?

Comment: Can we use Proc ANOVA? The result  looks a bit different than ANOVA table?

Comment: If you really want Two Way ANOVA then: proc glm data =new; class player round; model y = player round; run; From your data, the effect of player should be treated as random effect. But if you insist they are fixed effect, then use two way ANOVA.